# Can a machine be its own DHCP server for another interface?

Tags: network, dhcp

I was wondering if a single machine (with several network interfaces) can be, at the same time, a DHCP server and a DHCP client, that is the server would dynamically attribute an IP address to an other interface ?

Comment: Yes it is possible (at least with a DHCP relay) but what's the point of such a topology?

Comment: The goal was to use a single virtual machine as part of a course, install the DHCP server and test it in that VM.

Comment: Considering how easy it is to setup a VM, I would rather go for 2 VMs, this will be much more like a real life case.

Comment: Yes, I agree, and I think I will retain this solution. But my question was only by pure curiosity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cetainly it's possible, and indeed moderately common for small routers linking to ISPs.

The external interface to the ISP gets a dynamic address from the ISP (by LCP or DHCP as appropriate), and very often is a DHCP server for the local clients on some internal interface.

This is a portion of a Cisco router configuration with exactly that functionality:

```
ip dhcp pool 1
 network 192.168.241.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.241.1 
 dns-server 8.8.8.8 

interface Vlan1000
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
```

Comment: As I read the quesiton, it is about the same machine being both the DHCP client and the DHCP server that will respond for its own request.

Comment: Not exactly "for its own request". I assume the machine has TWO interfaces, one of them being dynamically assigned by the DHCP server that listens on the other one